# Blazor Maui Hybrid App architecture with API Microservices

Tags: razor, architecture, blazor, maui

I have Nearly 20 years of experience in building full-stack web-based applications using various flavors of .NET. Recently, I embarked on a new project where I aim to deploy the application to any device supported by Maui, while maintaining a consistent code base across platforms.

Here's the current setup I have in mind for my solution:

1. .NET Maui Blazor App: This will serve as the cross-platform user interface for the application.
2. Razor Class Library: I intend to build most, if not all, of the components within this library.
3. Blazor Server App: This will handle the web-based user interfaces.
4. ASP.NET Core WebAPI: I will utilize this for the API, leveraging Entity Framework and SQL Server.

I would appreciate guidance on how best to structure the Razor Class Library. Specifically, I have a couple of questions:

1. Are there any potential challenges or pitfalls I should be aware of when designing and sharing UI components from the Razor Class Library to other user interface projects?
2. What would be the most optimal and organized way to structure the Razor Class Library? Currently, I'm organizing components into folders based on their types."
3. Am I going to be able to design ALL of my components in this Razor Class Library?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth here's my take on your questions:

1. Challenges/Pitfalls.  It's very easy to let Css framework or application specific stuff polute your library.  In my code the `Blazr.Components` project is Css framework agnostic.   The `Blazr.Application.Components` is application specific.
2. Structure.  In general I believe in "screaming architecure" in base libraries and "screaming domain entities" in my application libraries.  So my base Grid code lives in `Blazr.Components/Grid` while implementation components for WeatherForecasts [components and page components] are in `Blazr.Application.UI/WeatherForecasts`.  My Namespaces aren't driven by folder structure.
3. All my components?  In your libraries (plural), yes.  In my solutions the Blazor Server project is just a deployment project, just as WASM and Maui are.  It only contains the code to build out the deployment: landing page, Css, services definitions, etc.  There are no components in my deployment projects.

Here's the project view of the current application [A workflow development] I'm working on.

[image]

Comment: This structure looks very similar to the old WCF applications.  What I meant to ask in question 3 is: Am I going to end up having to create components in my specific UI projects as well as my shared Razor Class Library?  It sounds like you have all of your components in one project, some components that are base components shared by other components and you have specific components for certain deployments. Are you connected to a database?  I haven't even thought about unit tests yet.  I was planning to do unit tests for the APIs but wasn't sure about the blazor components.